# JQuery setting a local storage variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having some trouble getting a local storage variable to store the proper value.  The jist of it is I want to display the contents of the local variable, then if the user clicks, it pulls the data from an .xml file, saving it to a local variable.

Problem is, that it doesn't save to the local variable properly.  I have tried a variety of syntax to get it to work and I am out of ideas.

Test site for it is located at http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~todtm/assignment2.html

Script Code:

```
function startAjax()
{
    $("#clickme").text("Calling server");
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "xmlpage.xml",
        success: callbackFunction,
        error: errorFunction
    });
}

function callbackFunction(data, info)
{
    var titles = $(data).find("title");
    if (titles && titles.length)
    {
        $("#results").text("result:" + titles.text());
        localStorage.setItem('titles', #results.text());
    }
    else
        errorFunction(data, "No titles");
}

function errorFunction(data, info)
{
    $("#clickme").text("error occurred:" + info);
}

$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $("#results").text(localStorage.getItem('titles'));
});
```

Comment: Which browser are you attempting this in? In Chrome if you open developer tools (F12) and click the console you can simply type localStorage to see what's stored there. localStorage.setItem('name','value') is all you need to do.

Comment: You're saving `nothing` in localStorage, and that's what appears when the page refreshes. What's the problem?

Comment: I changed #results.text() to 'nothing' for testing and didn't change it back before posting this code.  Where 'nothing' is I need the value that gets assigned to results.text

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you have a syntax error, need to get

```
localStorage.setItem('titles', $('#results').text());
```

or

```
localStorage.setItem('titles', titles.text());
```

Comment: thank you, that worked like a charm.  I am very new to jquery, and I keep forgetting about the $