# how to get value from input field and store in local storage and show into table in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html

how to get value from input feild and store in local storage and show into table in javascript

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text">
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input type="text">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
    </tr>

    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Stackoverflow isn't a free code sriting service or a *"how to"* tutorial service. The objective here is to help you fix **your code**. See [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Try this one,

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input id="name" type="text">
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input id="last" type="text">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name: <label class="name"></label></th>
        <th>Last Name: <label class="last_name"></label></th>
    </tr>

    </table>
    <button id="transfer">Transfer</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Using Jquery

```
$(function(){
  $('#transfer').on('click',function(){
   localStorage.setItem('name', $('#name').text());
   localStorage.setItem('last', $('#last').text());
   $('.name').text(localStorage.getItem('name'))
   $('.last_name').text(localStorage.getItem('last'))
 })

});
```

Storing in local storage : [JQuery setting a local storage variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17758135/jquery-setting-a-local-storage-variable)

Getting data in local storage : [Getting the value of a variable from localStorage from a different javascript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19861265/getting-the-value-of-a-variable-from-localstorage-from-a-different-javascript-fi)

Hope this help :)